# How to Dynamically add Fields to Flask Form?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a Flask application that requires a user to add a variable number of data points which will then be processed later on. The format that I am looking for is:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| (Text Field) | (Drop Down Selection) |
| (Text Field) | (Drop Down Selection) |

```
<button>Add Row</button>
```

I'm new to the whole Flask Environment and most of the YouTube tutorials focus on making things like log in pages where the number of fields is fixed. Is there a way to approach this issue? I've tried using the following:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, IntegerField
from wtforms.fields.core import FieldList, FormField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

class KeyValueForm(FlaskForm):
    key = StringField('Key', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=5)])
    value = SelectField('Data Type', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[('int', 'int'), ('dict', 'dict'), ('string', 'string'), ('boolean', 'boolean')])

class CreateLicenseForm(FlaskForm):

    product_name = StringField('Product Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2)])
    data = FieldList(FormField(KeyValueForm))

    def addEntry(self):
        self.data.append_entry(FormField(KeyValueForm))
```

and

```
<div class="content-section">
        <form action="">
            {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
            <fieldset class="formgroup">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Product</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.product_name.label(class='form-control-label') }}
                {{ form.product_name(class='form-control') }}
            </div>
            {% for field in form.data %}
            <p>{{ field }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="{{ form.addEntry() }}">Add Row</button>
    </div>
```